# checkbox with javascript magic attached does not uncheck

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a script where I use checkboxes and javascript to display additional items if the checkboxes are checked. 
This seems to be working just fine most of the time. 
There is one checkbox however that is giving problems. 
I assume because of the javascript magic associated with it. 
When checking it and then unchecking it, the checkbox always returns isset after post.

Never checking the checkbox and submitting returns not set as it should.
Checking and submitting returns checked as it should
checking, unchecking and submitting returns ... checked!
I have set up an example on http://vampke.uphero.com/tst.php

Here is the code:

```php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if(isset($_POST['se_currentitem'])) echo "CHECKBOX = ISSET";
else echo "CHECKBOX = NOT SET";
}

echo <<< EOD

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">
.hiddenDiv {display: none;}
.visibleDiv{display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

var currentitem = 0;

function toggle_currentitem(){
mydiv = document.getElementById("currentitemcontainer");
if (document.getElementById('se_currentitem').checked){
mydiv.className = "visibleDiv";
if(currentitem==0){
addcurrentitem();
}
}
else {
mydiv.className = "hiddenDiv";
}
}

function addcurrentitem(){
currentitem++;
var newitem = document.createElement('div');
newitem.id = currentitem;
newitem.innerHTML= "<p><strong><em>new item</em></strong><br /><label>select a number:</label><select name='se_currentitem[]'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></p>";

document.getElementById('currentitem').appendChild(newitem); 
}

//-->
</script>
<form action ="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" id="se_currentitem" name="se_currentitem" value="1" onchange="toggle_currentitem()" /><label for="se_currentitem">click the checkbox to activate the items</label> <br />

<div id="currentitemcontainer" class="hiddenDiv">
<div id="currentitem"></div>
<a id='addnewcurrent' onclick='addcurrentitem()'>add item</a>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What is the script that is affecting the checkbox?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. Othewise, this question can not be useful to anyone but you and will be closed as too localised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox is named `se_currentitem` and the `select` menu is named `se_currentitem[]`. PHP's `$_POST` array treats these as the same.

- When you check the box, you create the `select` menu.
- When you uncheck the box, you hide the `select` menu, but it remains in the DOM, and is submitted by the browser. Notice in the Network inspector (or tcpflow, etc.). that the browser submits both `se_currentitem` and `se_currentitem[]`.

You should rename the checkbox so it is not called `se_currentitem` (or rename the `select` menu so it is not called `se_currentitem[]`).

Comment: Thank you SO much! I have been struggling for hours on this!
I did not know this would be a problem.